# How to turn transparent logos gray

Tags: python, opencv

I have these following logos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And I want to turn them gray using this function:

```
def to_grayscale(path):
    return Image.fromarray(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

`path` is just the file path to one of these logos. What ends up happening is that some of the logos don't show at all. For example, the logitect logo. It is completely invisible despite being pitch black.

Is there anyway I can turn these logos into solid gray?

Comment: Do you want the transparent parts to be uniform gray or the logo text to be uniform gray? What exactly do you want. Can you show an example? Your function just reads the image and converts from color to grayscale. It does not make it uniform gray. Your function will also ignore the transparency and you will see whatever color or texture is below the transparency.

Comment: @fmw42 I want to make it uniform gray while maintaining the transparency..

Comment: You want to make what part uniform gray?  The logo text or whatever is under the transparency?

Comment: Whatever is under the transparency..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the text gray, but keep your transparency, then do the following in Python/OpenCV

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('google.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# extract alpha channel
alpha = img[:, :, 3]

# create solid gray image
gray = np.full((img.shape), (128,128,128,0))

# put alpha channel into gray image
result = gray.copy()
result[:,:,3] = alpha

# save output
cv2.imwrite('google_gray_transparent.png', result)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your code throws this error: `ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box`

Comment: This comment makes no sense to me. Where does the error occur. There is no box involved. I am using Python 3.7 and OpenCV 3.4.8

Comment: I fixed it. I had to turn `result` into a PIL image

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to make the image under the transparency to gray in Python/OpenCV

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('google.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# extract alpha channel
alpha = img[:, :, 3]

# extract the bgr image
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

# make gray where alpha is zero
bgr[alpha==0] = (128,128,128)

# put alpha channel into brg image
b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr)
result = img.copy()
result[:,:,0] = b
result[:,:,1] = g
result[:,:,2] = r
result[:,:,3] = alpha

# save output
cv2.imwrite('google_gray_under_transparency1.png', bgr)
cv2.imwrite('google_gray_under_transparency2.png', result)

cv2.imshow('alpha', alpha)
cv2.imshow('bgr', bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

BGR:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes it is. The first image shows what is under the alpha channel. The second image has the first image with the original alpha channel over it. I thought you wanted to preserve the alpha channel. If you do not, the just stop at the first image. If I misunderstand what you want, please explain in more detail.

Comment: I want to preserve the transparent background while turning "Google" into gray

Comment: That was what I posted earlier below. See my first post.